# How do I make my cloned game objects global, so I can use them outside of the function in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just recently got into Unity 3D and currently working on one of my first own projects. For the game im making, I need a spawner function, that respawns a clone of the enemy as soon as the enemy falls off the platform. This is the code I have right now:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    public float spawnHeight = 0.75f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spawnEnemy();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (enemyClone.transform.position.y < -10)
        {
            Destroy(enemyClone);
            spawnEnemy();
        }
    }

    public void spawnEnemy()
    {
        var enemyPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), spawnHeight, Random.Range(-5, 5));
        var enemyClone = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, enemyPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

The function spawnEnemy itself works fine, since it creates an enemy on game start, tho further enemies aren't spawned. I get the message: "Assets\spawner.cs(21,21): error CS0103: The name 'enemyClone' does not exist in the current context".

I do see why I get the message, don't know how to make enemyClone globally available however.

Thanks to everybody in advance,

bezunyl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `spawnEnemy()` function, you say `var enemyClone = Instantiate(...);`. enemyClone is a local variable that can only be used within the `spawnEnemy` function, or at least that's how you've written it.

If you want to use the enemyClone outside of the `spawnEnemy` function, you need to declare the enemyClone variable outside of the function. (The example below will work if you DON'T want enemyClone to be accessible to other GameObjects)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    public float spawnHeight = 0.75f;

    private GameObject enemyClone //Added to allow enemyClone to be used anywhere in the class

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spawnEnemy();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (enemyClone.transform.position.y < -10)
        {
            Destroy(enemyClone);
            spawnEnemy();
        }
    }

    public void spawnEnemy()
    {
        var enemyPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), spawnHeight, Random.Range(-5, 5));
        enemyClone = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, enemyPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Now if you want enemyClone to be accessible by other GameObjects, then you'll want to make the `enemyClone` variable `public` instead of `private`. If you don't want it to show up in the inspector, add `[HideInInspector]` above the declaration of enemyClone, as shown below:

```
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject enemyClone;
```

Your issue is based on `scope`. You might want to research it, it's important to know.

> The scope of a variable determines its visibility to the rest of a program.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609145&seqNum=4

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got it working with that.

Answer (score 0):

Spawning GameObject on demand is expensive. Instead of spawning it everytime, you should pool the GameObject.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
    public Enemy enemyPrefab;
    public List<Enemy> enemyPool;
    public const SPAWN_HEIGHT = 0.75f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemyPool = new List<Enemy>();
        spawnEnemy();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Despawn(Enemy deadEnemy)
    {
        deadEnemy.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        enemyPool.Add(deadEnemy);
    }

    public void spawnEnemy() {
        Enemy newEnemy;
        if (enemyPool.Count > 0) {
            newEnemy = enemyPool[0];
            enemyPool.Remove(0);
        } else {
            newEnemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab);
        }
        newEnemy.Init(this);

        newEnemy.position =  new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), SPAWN_HEIGHT, Random.Range(-5, 5));
        newEnemy.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    private Spawner spawner;
    private const float DEATH_POSITION_Y = -10;

    public void Init(Spawner spawner) {
        this.spawner = spawner;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (transform.position.y < DEATH_POSITION_Y) {
            spawner.Despawn(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will look into it again, since it looks pretty complicated.